# How to sort a ArrayList so that the center has the largest element?

Tags: java, sorting

There is a need to sort the ArrayList in such a way that the center had the largest element and the tails on the sides.

For example:

> 0 2 3 1 0 4 5 3 0 2 4 1

I want:

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0

How can this be achieved? My method looks like this, I sort by ascending, but needed as I described above.

```
public void generateSpeedFly(int timesec, double Speed){
        Random r = new Random();
        listSpeed = new ArrayList<>(timesec);
        listSpeed.add(0,0.);
        for (int i = 1; i <= timesec-4; i++) {
            listSpeed.add((double) r.nextInt((int) Speed));
        }
        Collections.sort(listSpeed);
        listSpeed.add(listSpeed.size(), Speed);
        minSpeed = listSpeed.get(0);
        maxSpeed = listSpeed.get(listSpeed.size() - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < listSpeed.size(); i++){
            TotalSpeed += listSpeed.get(i);
        }
        average = TotalSpeed / listSpeed.size();
        TotalSpeed = 0;
    }
```

Comment: That isn't sorted; divide the list into two sublists. Sort one half ascending, sort one half descending. Rejoin the two sublists.

Comment: If the input is "1 2 3 4 5" , what should be the output? Your question is not clear. I understand the middle one willl be 5 but not able to get what should be the first two and last two .

Comment: I think in that case output will be 1 2 5 4 3....

Comment: @zenwraight why not `1 3 5 4 2` ? :)

Answer (score 2):

A simple idea that come into my mind would be so split the list into two parts, sort the left one ascending, and the right one descending.

If we take your example:

> 0 2 3 1 0 4 5 3 0 2 4 1

The two parts would be:

> 0 2 3 1 0 4
>   5 3 0 2 4 1

We sort the first one ascending and the second one descending:

> 0 0 1 2 3 4
>   5 4 3 2 1 0

And we finally obtain:

> 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0

That's more or less what we want. I don't know if there exist cases where this algorithm would produce an undesired result. Probably if the array is badly balanced at start, the result would also bee a little unbalanced. Then come my second, perhaps more robust, idea:

1. We sort the entire array
2. Take each element in turn and alternatively push them in front and in back of the output
3. Split the output into two parts left and right
4. Assemble the two parts in reverse order

Taking again your example:

> 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5

Step 1:

> input: 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5
>   output: 0 0

Step 2:

> input: 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5
>   output: 0 0 0 1

Step 3:

> input: 2 3 3 4 4 5
>   output: 1 0 0 0 1 2

Step 4:

> input: 3 4 4 5
>   output: 2 1 0 0 0 1 2 3

Finally we obtain:

> 5 4 3 2 1 0 0 0 1 2 3 4

At this stage, that's exactly the opposite of what we want. So we split:

> Left: 5 4 3 2 1 0
>   Right: 0 0 1 2 3 4

And then finally we get:

> 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0

In fact, you can avoid the final split and reassemble step if you initially sort the array descending instead of ascending. Sort your initial array so that the first element is the one that you would like to see in the center at the end.

There again, I don't know if there exist cases that would produce unexpected results. Do some math to prove or disprove it if you like. I don't think so though.

Comment: What if the list is not symmetrical ?

Comment: My first algorithm will produce an unbalanced result, but my second one will produce something as balanced as it can be. Consider what happens with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8: 
with the first algorithm you will get 1,2,3,4,8,7,6,5, but the second will do 1,3,5,7,8,6,4,2. 

If you want to compensate unbalances and produce something like 2,3,6,7,8,5,4,1 then you may change the insertion alternation from L,R,L,R,... to L,R,R,L,L,R,R,... or L,R,R,L,L,R,L,R,R,L,L,R,L,...
but then it's probably getting tricky to produce something where the sum of the two sub-arrays are equal with eachother.

Comment: Nice answer  .

Answer (score 1):

I offer to use temporary array. It takes `O(n)` memory, but it works.

```
public static void sort(int[] arr) {
    int[] tmp = Arrays.stream(arr).sorted().toArray();

    for (int i = 0, l = 0, r = arr.length - 1; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            arr[l++] = tmp[i];
        else
            arr[r--] = tmp[i];
    }
}
```

After think a while, I have found suitable solution without using `O(n)` memory, but a little bit slower:

```
public static void sort(int[] arr) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);

    for (int l = 1, r = arr.length - 1; l < r; l++, r--) {
        // shift 1 position left
        int tmp = arr[l];
        System.arraycopy(arr, l + 1, arr, l, r - l);
        arr[r] = tmp;
    }
}
```

*Test:*
Both solutions provide same result:

*Input:*  `[ 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 4, 5, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1 ]`

*Output:* `[ 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 ]`

Answer (score 0):

```
// init
Integer[] result = new Integer[arr.length];
Integer[] arr = {0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 4, 5, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1};
List<Integer> listSorted = Arrays.asList(arr);

// simple sort, O(N*log(N))
Collections.sort(listSorted);

// fill result array O(n) 
int size = listSorted.size();
for(int i = 0; i < size / 2 ; i++) {
    result[size / 2 - i ] = listSorted.get(size - i * 2 - 1);
    if(size / 2 + i + 1 < size) {
        result[size / 2 + i + 1] = listSorted.get(size - i * 2 - 2);
    }
}
```

Result {0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0, O(N*log(N))